# keep getting "Next without for" while I start with for

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that runs on cell changes but every time I want to run it it keeps giving me "Next without for" or "double declaration within given range"
Here's the code:

```
Dim Lvl As Range
Set Lvl = Range("A5:A44")
Dim Full, Medium, Poor
Dim r As Long
For r = 5 To 44
Full = StrComp(Range("A" & r), Data.Range("A2"), 0)
Medium = StrComp(Range("A" & r), Data.Range("A3"), 0)
Poor = StrComp(Range("A" & r), Data.Range("A4"), 0)
If Not Intersect(Target, Lvl) Is Nothing Then
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = r To 44
        If Full = 0 Then
            Range("I" & r).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown((Range("B" & r) * 1), 0)
        ElseIf Medium = 0 Then
            Range("I" & r).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown((Range("B" & r) * (3 / 4)), 0)
        ElseIf Poor = 0 Then
            Range("I" & r).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown((Range("B" & r) * (1 / 2)), 0)
        Else
            Range("I" & r).Value = 0
        End If


        If Not Range("A" & r) = Range("A" & r).Offset(-1, 0) And Not Range("A" & r) = A5 Then
            If Range("A" & r).Offset(-1, 0) = Full And Range("A" & r) = Medium Then
                Range("I" & i).Value = Range("I" & i).Value + 1
            ElseIf Range("A" & r).Offset(-1, 0) = Medium And Range("A" & r) = Poor Then
                Range("I" & i).Value = Range("I" & i).Value + 1
            ElseIf Range("A" & r).Offset(-1, 0) = Full And Range("A" & r) = Poor Then
                Range("I" & i).Value = Range("I" & i).Value + 2
            End If
        End If
    Next
End If
Next
```

The Double Declaration Error I am getting probably has to do with the fact that I am using r = 5 To 44 AND i = r To 44 
But I needed a way to get the `Range("I" & i).value` to work

Comment: Have you tried adding an end if after your last else if to see if that fixes it?

Comment: There is an `End If` missing right before `Next` if you indent your code correcty it is much easier to see. Additionally I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit` and declare all your variables properly: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.

Comment: You are missing an `End If` after `Range("I" & i).Value = Range("I" & i).Value + 2`

Comment: You did properly indent your code (good!), so it is easy to see that you have one missing `End If` (Well, @Pᴇʜ edited it, but it was still visible in the unedited version)

Comment: @VincentG Yes you are right, but actually VBA itself dosen't care about indentation (it is only for human readability). That's why *technically* the `End If` **before** `Next` is missing and not the other one (which you suggested) ;) even if it looked the other way round because of the (wrong) indentation. • This is also why you get a `Next without for` error and not a `missing end if` error.

Comment: I think I am blind, I have three If statements, one is the Overlapping one, the second is the StrComp with formula thing and the third is where I add +1 or +2 , all three have an End if there...
Even with the edited version I still get the    Next without for
error

Comment: @graviadamon. Look closely at the edited code in your Q, there is clearly a missing `End If` just before the `Next`

Comment: @graviaDamon see my answer I marked it with comments in the code. And why did you put a `r = r + 1` there now? That's the position where the `End If` should be.

Comment: the r = r + 1 should be for the next iteration of the code, it needs to keep running till r = 44

Comment: Code and Question Updated, Thanks all for showing me how blind I can be when working on this for days

Comment: @graviaDamon The issue is that you declare `i` inside a loop. Move `Dim i As Integer` out of your `For r = 5 To 44` loop, otherwise you `Dim i` over and over again for each iteration of `r`. Also note that row counting variables must be of type `Long` because Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle. Change it to `Dim i As Long` and put it outside your loops.

Comment: Thanks, got it now! my code still isn't working how I want it to work but now I get it without errors :P thanks all for helping!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

There is an `End If` missing right before `Next`

```
Dim Lvl As Range
Set Lvl = Range("A5:A44")
Dim Full, Medium, Poor
r = 5
Full = StrComp(Range("A" & r), Data.Range("A2"), 0)
Medium = StrComp(Range("A" & r), Data.Range("A3"), 0)
Poor = StrComp(Range("A" & r), Data.Range("A4"), 0)

If Not Intersect(Target, Lvl) Is Nothing Then
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = r To 44
        If Full = 0 Then
            Range("I" & r).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown((Range("B" & r) * 1), 0)
        ElseIf Medium = 0 Then
            Range("I" & r).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown((Range("B" & r) * (3 / 4)), 0)
        ElseIf Poor = 0 Then
            Range("I" & r).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown((Range("B" & r) * (1 / 2)), 0)
        Else
            Range("I" & r).Value = 0
        End If


        If Not Range("A" & r) = Range("A" & r).Offset(-1, 0) And Not Range("A" & r) = A5 Then 
        '^^-- this one is not closed by End If

            If Range("A" & r).Offset(-1, 0) = Full And Range("A" & r) = Medium Then
            '^^-- this is AAA
                Range("I" & i).Value = Range("I" & i).Value + 1
            ElseIf Range("A" & r).Offset(-1, 0) = Medium And Range("A" & r) = Poor Then
                Range("I" & i).Value = Range("I" & i).Value + 1
            ElseIf Range("A" & r).Offset(-1, 0) = Full And Range("A" & r) = Poor Then
                Range("I" & i).Value = Range("I" & i).Value + 2
            End If '<-- this closes the one I marked with AAA

        End If  '<-- missing here !!!

    Next
End If
```

Comment: the "End if" you are commenting on I already have in place two lines up. maybe it is the indentation, but I really thought I was going mad. but all of you just did not see because of my indentations... still getting the same errors if I space it like you did

Comment: @graviaDamon see my edited answer. The other one closes the other `If` statement I marked with `'^^-- this is AAA`

Comment: Right, did not see that one, thanks XD (now I'm laughing at myself for being stupid)
but now I get double declaration error
I'm Posting an updated version of the code